# How to take an input from a banner displayed inside a Jframe

Tags: java, spring-boot, swing, jtextfield, jeditorpane

I am working on a springboot standalone application which toggles b/w display and hiding a banner based on some situation.

Now I have got some requirement to enable the user to remove that banner by entering some pin or password as an exception to toggle logic.

I am wondering is it feasible that I can create a textfield inside the jframe or inside html page that's being displayed in JFrame to take the user input (I know html page can't be submitted) or do I need to change html to jsp or something else ?

Please suggest.

Code:

```
public class BringUpFrame {

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BringUpFrame.class);
    private static final int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private static final int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private static final int TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
    private static final HWND HWND_TOPMOST = new HWND(Pointer.createConstant(-1));
    private static JFrame frmOpt;
   
    private static String hostname;

    
    public static JFrame ShowBanner() throws IOException {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        String urlText = null;
        String ScrnResol = getScreenResolution();
        String[] ScreenResolution = ScrnResol.split(",");
        try {
            width = Integer.parseInt(ScreenResolution[0]);
            height = Integer.parseInt(ScreenResolution[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            logger.error("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
        }
        //Creating Frame
        frmOpt = new JFrame("Banner");
        frmOpt.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmOpt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frmOpt.setUndecorated(true);
        frmOpt.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f));
        frmOpt.setVisible(true);
        frmOpt.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frmOpt.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //bringToForeground(getHWND(frmOpt));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        LayoutManager layout = new FlowLayout();
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
        jEditorPane.setEditable(false);
        try {
            
            String urlText=IOUtils.toString(BringUpFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("banner.htm"));
            jEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");
            jEditorPane.setText(urlText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while executing showBanner: {}", e);
            jEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");
            jEditorPane.setText("<html>Page not found.</html>");
        }
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jEditorPane);
        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        panel.add(jScrollPane);
        frmOpt.add(panel);
        frmOpt.pack();
        frmOpt.setVisible(true);
        return frmOpt;

    }

    public static void disposeBanner() {
        frmOpt.dispose();
        logger.info("Banner Closed");
    }

    private static void bringToForeground(HWND clientWindow) { 
        User32Ext.INSTANCE.SetWindowPos(clientWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS); 

    }

    private static HWND getHWND(Component comp) {
        return new HWND(Native.getComponentPointer(comp));
    }


    public static String getScreenResolution() {
        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
        String resolution = width + "," + height;
        logger.info("Screen Resolution is (width,height) : " + resolution);
        return resolution;


    }
}
```

Currently banner is looking like below:

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: *is it feasible that I can create a textfield inside the jframe ... to take the user input* - maybe use a JOptionPane. See [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: @camickr Thanks for commenting. Link that you shared explained how to have user input field in jframe. What I am looking is I am displaying content from html as of now in Jframe. Along with that I want a input field on the screen.